# How can I obtain the group of "dirty" rows or cells from a DataGridview?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, data-binding, datagridview

I am working with a DataGridView filled up from a view in my database.

Being a view (maybe I'm wrong) I can't use the TableAdapter.Update() method so I need to know the altered cells from the DataGridView so I can update the values in their respective tables programatically.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to update Views http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068(v=SQL.80).aspx

You can also get the edited rows by called `DataTable.GetChanges()`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using a Strongly Typed Dataset bounded with the view, so I'll have to update it manually.

Answer (score 0):

A DataGridView is only a transforming layer above the bounded `DataTable`. All changes applied to the view are directly materialized in the underlying `DataTable`. You can use the `.DataSource` property of your view to get a reference for this DataTable.

You have to create a `DataAdapter` with the appropriate `SqlCommand` objects for insert, update and delete.

After doing so you can use the `DataAdapter.Update(DataTable table)` method to apply all changes to the database.